# Changing default column name for navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have following class

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Tree Tree { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; protected set; }
    public string Index { get; protected set; }
}
```

and I want to change default database's column name of property Tree. As default entity framework looking for "TreeId" column in databse, but our name's convention says that this column should be named as "tree_id"

If I try to set it as below:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<TreeItem>().Property(t => t.Tree).HasColumnName("tree_id");
```

Ef throws me an exception with message:

> Cannot call Property for the property 'Tree' on entity type 'TreeItem'
>   because it is configured as a navigation property. Property can only
>   be used to configure scalar properties.

Is it possible to change default column name of property Tree from "TreeId" to "tree_id"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using MapKey():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TreeItem>()
            .HasRequired(it => it.Tree)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("tree_id"));
```

**EDIT**

For EF Core, you might have to use a work around as mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5893):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TreeItem>()
            .Property<long>("TreeId")
            .HasColumnName("tree_id");
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that the EF Core does not have "Map" method

Comment: sorry..my bad! have updated the answer..looks like you might have to live with that work around unless you include the FK as a property in the model

Comment: Ok it works good. But in my opition it should be changed, because it's a little bit unintuitive, but still better than using TreeId Property inside model.

Answer (score 3):

I always use a virtual objects when relating two entities to each other. When doing this you can also specify the column name for the FK as below:

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Column("tree_id")]
    public int TreeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TreeId")]
    public virtual Tree Tree { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; protected set; }
    public string Index { get; protected set; }
}

public class Tree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Generates this table in the database (I just created the Tree class as example for testing) If it's id is also a long make sure to change the datatype of the TreeId in the TreeItem class too.

[image]

Comment: This approach is good, and I know it, but I want to remove TreeId property because it is not nescessery, it works good without it. The problem is that EF looks for TreeId column in database (I have tree_id). It's not a big problem because possibly I could change it, but I would rather not do this